# Boost audio volume more than 100% in react native

Tags: android, react-native, audio

My app is music player and some of the mp3's have lower volume. I want to Boost audio volume more than 100% in react native.

I have to tried this plugin:

- react-native-volume-control
- react-native-system-setting
- react-native-audio-manager
- react-native-sound

Comment: Can you provide some code example of what you acheived so far?

Comment: Some of the mp3's have lower volume. So i want to Boost audio volume more than 100% @WiliamBrochensquejunior

Comment: can you add reproducible git demo here?

Answer (score 3):

No, It's not possible, You have to increase the volume of the file that is playing like for example the vlc player does when you increase the volume beyond 100%. It has nothing to do with the volume you set to the phone, it just compensates for files which have a more quiet audio track.

You can try Web Audio API

```
function amplifyMedia(mediaElem, multiplier) {
  var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext),
      result = {
        context: context,
        source: context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElem),
        gain: context.createGain(),
        media: mediaElem,
        amplify: function(multiplier) { result.gain.gain.value = multiplier; },
        getAmpLevel: function() { return result.gain.gain.value; }
      };
  result.source.connect(result.gain);
  result.gain.connect(context.destination);
  result.amplify(multiplier);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement a Native Module yourself for js to call setStereoVolume() on your AudioTrack if you are using AudioTrack.Or if you are using ExoPlayer to play music,try implement a custom AudioProcessor to copy each channel and apply the amplification.